# Android animation is laggy \ slow with background

Tags: android, animation, android-asynctask

I wanted to animate something very small just to try it out....BUT:

animation works perfect with no background.

as I set the background of my main layout the animation is super laggy \slow with very low frame rate.

here is my code:

Main Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<!-- android:background="@drawable/backgroundhotpink"  -->


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flickit"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:src="@drawable/switch_on" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="message"
    android:textSize="30sp" 
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/message"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:rotation="-45"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="23sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startStopGame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="Start Game" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/socketImageview"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/flickit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/socket" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Time"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <set android:shareInterpolator="false"                   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.4"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.6"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="300" />

</set>
```

Animation SyncTask:

```
protected Void doInBackground(View... params) {
    final View v = params[0];
    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.scale_back_fowrad));

        }
    });
    return null;


}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Are you seeing this "lag" on the emulator, or a physical device?

Comment: Physical device. Htc one.

Answer (score 3):

This problem arises due to size and format of image you are using for background. Do following to avoid this problem:

1. Keep image size less than 500 kb
2. Use png format for the image

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your images are in PNG format.

Answer (score 0):

If there are resource intensive animations running and if the content of your views is changing, it would be best to optimize the size of the views in your layout by setting a value other than wrap content.  That way, view measurement calculations will not have to be calculated every time the view is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better option than changing the format of the image. If you use images then generate the image in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi modes and add to the project. It is the real reason why android animations get laggy. Try something like Adobe XD to export the image in different modes and add them in the correct drawable folder.

These are the mdpi, hdpi,..... folders
[image: These are the mdpi, hdpi,..... folders]